# Launch activity when user taps on a notification from the lockscreen

Tags: android, notifications, android-pendingintent, lockscreen

I want to be able to tap on a notification when the device is locked and launch an activity without unlocking the device.

I added some flags to the activity in the `onCreate()` method that allow the activity to be displayed when the device is locked:

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

This is the code that creates the notification:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        intent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

Notification notification = new Notification.Builder(this)
        .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
        .setContentTitle("Title")
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_menu_more)
        .build();

NotificationManager notificationManager =
        (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

notificationManager.notify(1, notification);
```

I also added `showOnLockScreen="true"` to the manifest:

```
<activity
    android:name=".MainActivity"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:showOnLockScreen="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Things that are working:

- The activity is shown when the device is locked (for example, if I leave the activity on foreground and lock the phone the activity remains on foreground without the need of unlocking the phone)
- If I tap the notification when the phone is locked, it asks me to unlock it and then the activity is shown

I want to be able to do the same but without unlocking the device.
What am I missing?

Answer (score -2):

Try this!!!

```
private NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder;

Intent notifyIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
    notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notifyIntent, 0);
    mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setSmallIcon(getNotificationIcon())
            .setContent(remoteViews)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .setOnlyAlertOnce(true)
            .setOngoing(true);
```

this is method get notification icon on device 5.0 and lower

```
private int getNotificationIcon() {
    boolean useWhiteIcon = (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP);
    return useWhiteIcon ? R.drawable.notification_icon : R.mipmap.ic_launcher;
}
```

Remove code below in onCreate

```
Window window = this.getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
```

Comment: The `remoteViews` variable is not declared (nor assigned).

Comment: I tried the rest of your set up and it's not fixing my issue. Are you sure this code allows an activity to be launched from a notification on the lockscreen without unlocking the device?

Comment: notifyIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);